# c# collections List class

Tags: c#

Greetings!

I am using List class.I will define my code below.

```
List<c1> lis = new List<c1>();
```

where c1 is class. 
I want to find index of particular item in List.say in list i have, 10,20,30,40 inside List.In this how i find the index of 30.Please help me to get a solution.

Thank You
Regards
Jennie

Comment: You are adding the same `c` over and over again, aren't you (and change an element of `na` on the same `c`)? Apart from this, if you know the number of items that you add to the list when initializing it, I recommend you to pass it as a constructor argument. Since `List<T>` uses a `T[]` as a backend (array list), the data might be copied around a few times as the array need to be re-initialized when the items exceed the length. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx "Remarks"...

Comment: You've removed some code making this question impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what are you looking for? [List.IndexOf Method (T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
lis.IndexOf(value)
```

That should return the first index of the requested  value.

Answer (score 0):

`c1 c = new c1();` should be INSIDE the loop.

Actualy, what is your code supposed to represent? Are you aware you have Array inside a list. So in your case, you end up with List with 4 items of same instance of single object, that has array of 4 items with strings "0","1","2","3". You should fix this first before you ask your question again.